# Get unique list items by nested dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have lists as dictionary values nested within another dictionary named `data`. I've been trying to find a quick way to get all unique list items from a specific nested key, like `key1` or `key2`.

I came up with the following function by this doesn't seem very efficient. Any ideas how I can speed this up and be a bit more pythonic?

**Python function**

```
def get_uniq_by_value(data, val_name):
    results = []
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        for item in value[val_name]:
            if item not in results:
                results.append(item)
    return results
```

**Example Data**

```
data = {
"top1": {
    "key1": [
        "there is no spoon", "but dictionaries are hard",
    ],
    "key2": [
        "mad max fury road was so good",
    ]
},
"top2": {
    "key1": [
        "my item", "foo bar"
    ],
    "key2": [
        "blah", "more junk"
    ]
},
```

Comment: No, order doesn't matter at all in the results

Comment: Have you considered a `set`, then? And why iterate over `iteritems` if you never use the `key`? Note that you'll crash with `KeyError` if one of the nested dictionaries doesn't have the `val_name` key.

Comment: Good point! Also, the data will always have `key1` and `key2` in every nested dictionary. If there are no items the list is left blank.

I haven't really used `set` before... Can I just append to it and only the unique values are kept?

Comment: @deadbits yes, `set.add` will quietly ignore duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter you can use `set` / set comprehension to get the desired result -

```
def get_uniq_by_value(data, val_name):
    return {val for value in data.values() for val in value.get(val_name,[])}
```

If you want a list as a result, you can use `list()` over the set comprehension to convert the resulting set to a list before returning.

Demo -

```
>>> def get_uniq_by_value(data, val_name):
...     return {val for value in data.values() for val in value.get(val_name,[])}
...
>>> data = {
... "top1": {
...     "key1": [
...         "there is no spoon", "but dictionaries are hard",
...     ],
...     "key2": [
...         "mad max fury road was so good",
...     ]
... },
... "top2": {
...     "key1": [
...         "my item", "foo bar"
...     ],
...     "key2": [
...         "blah", "more junk"
...     ]
... }}
>>> get_uniq_by_value(data,"key1")
{'but dictionaries are hard', 'my item', 'foo bar', 'there is no spoon'}
```

---

As indicated in the comments below, if the order is important and `data` is already an `collections.OrderedDict` of `OrderedDict`, you can use a new `OrderedDict` , and add the elements from the list as keys, `OrderedDict` would avoid any duplication and preserves the order in which the keys were added.

You can do this in one line as well using `OrderedDict.fomkeys` as indicated in the comments. Example -

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def get_uniq_by_value(data, val_name):
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(val for value in data.values() for val in value.get(val_name,[])))
```

Please note, this would only work is `data` is a nested OrderedDict, because otherwise `data`'s elements would not be in any specific order at all to begin with.

Demo -

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = OrderedDict([
... ("top1", OrderedDict([
...     ("key1", [
...         "there is no spoon", "but dictionaries are hard",
...     ]),
...     ("key2", [
...         "mad max fury road was so good",
...     ])
... ])),
... ("top2", OrderedDict([
...     ("key1", [
...         "my item", "foo bar"
...     ]),
...     ("key2", [
...         "blah", "more junk"
...     ])
... ]))])
>>>
>>> def get_uniq_by_value(data, val_name):
...     return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(val for value in data.values() for val in value.get(val_name,[])))
...
>>> get_uniq_by_value(data,"key1")
['there is no spoon', 'but dictionaries are hard', 'my item', 'foo bar']
```

Comment: And if order does matter, converting to a `collections.OrderedDict` using `OrderedDict.fromkeys`, then wrapping that in a `list` will preserve order while removing duplicates as a one-liner.

Comment: Well, `data` would also need to be an ordereddict for that to work.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have also added that method to the answer , with a note that `data` would also need to be a nested `OrderedDict` for it to work.